# Splunk - Lookup values + static search string = output with count

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I want to perform a search where I need to use a static search string + input from a csv file with usernames:

1. Search query-
                  `index=someindex host=host*p* "STATIC_SEARCH_STRING"`
2. Value from users.csv where the list is like this- *Please note that User/UserList is NOT a field in my Splunk*:
   `**UserList**
   User1
   User2
   User3
   .
   .
   UserN`

I have tried using multiple one of them being-
`| inputlookup users.csv | join [search index=someindex host=host*p* "STATIC_SEARCH_STRING"] | lookup  users.csv UserList OUTPUT UserList as User| stats count by User`

The above one just outputs the list of users with count as '1' - which I assume it is getting from the table itself.

When I try searching events for a single user like- 
`index=someindex host=host*p* "User1" "STATIC_SEARCH_STRING"`. I get 100's of events for that user.

Can someone please help me with this?
Sorry if this is a noob question, I have been trying to learn splunk in order to reduce my workload and am stuck here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this query?  Perhaps there is another way.

Comment: @RichG So I want to make sure that none of the users have any issues accessing the application. So my query would search for the Static search string + username. [there are around 10k Users]

Once I have this, I can then setup an alert for it if any user has less than say 10 events generated in a particular given time.

Comment: If you don't have a 'user' field in your index, what connects indexed events to lookup file entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
index=someindex host=host*p* "STATIC_SEARCH_STRING" [ | inputlookup users.csv | fields UserList | rename UserList as query]
```

What is happening here is that there is a sub-search, which does an inputlookup on the users.csv file. We then use `fields` to ensure there is only a single field (`UserList`) in the data. We then rename that field to `query`. This is a special field in sub-searches; when the sub-search returns the field `query`, it is expanded out into the expression `(field_value_1) OR (field_value_2) OR ...`.

This expression is then appended to the original search string, so the final search that Splunk executes is `index=someindex host=host*p* "STATIC_SEARCH_STRING" ("alice") OR ("bob") OR ("charlie")`

This approach is outlined at https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.3/Search/Changetheformatofsubsearchresults

You can also look at the Splunk format command, https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Format if you need to alter the sub-search's expression format, for example, adding `*` around each returned expression.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Also, thank you to everyone else for taking the time to help me out here with multiple of my problems!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing the search inside out

What I *think* you may want is the following:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp host=host*p* User=*
| search 
    [| inputlookup users.csv ]
| stats count by User
```

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use the *values* in your lookup as a filter on the data (ie, only where `User` is in that list)

If that is the case, the above will do just that

If you need to make the fieldnames match because the lookup table has a different name, change the subsearch to the following:

```
    [| inputlookup users.csv
     | rename lookup_field_name as User ]
```

Comment: Thank you. The above query posted by you gives 0 results. 
I again cross-checked to confirm if that was the case but as I said, each of the users has 100's of events generated for them.

Comment: @messi.torres28 - really need some sample event data to be able to help you any better than mere guessing :)